# MapActivity Crashes when to Intent

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a side drawer in my application. When I click on the map options, the app crashes when I do the Intent. Initially, I created a map application as a separate project and it works very well, it means there is no problem with API-KEY

**MainActivity.class**

```
case 2:
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
break;
```

**MapsActivity.class**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // the following line crashes
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
```

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Here is the LogCat:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.xxx.xxxx/com.example.xxx.xxxx.MapsActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class fragment

Comment: Could you please share the logcat messages?

Comment: I have added `logcat` message.

Comment: Try removing `xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your `activity_maps.xml` file. It's working fine in my code without it.

Comment: it gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot your class attribute in your layout, add this inside fragment

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Comment: its metinoned as "name" i guess in the code..which is not needed according to me..

Comment: I too had same problem, solved in the same manner..visit this for your refernce:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198863/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-an

Comment: Nope. they are intergancable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inflate view when you add view to `setContentView()`.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout. activity_maps, null, false);
setContentView(view);
setUpMapIfNeeded();
```

if itsn't working, Please check [this](https://github.com/zumrywahid/showmemate.git) project if you need more info. i have uploaded a drawer based location app

Answer (score 0):

Check the AndroidManifest.xml file if it contains this meta information:

```
<meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

or

```
<meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Based on this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start)(step 2), Google Play services package should be added to Android Studio; to do this you must add it to the AndroidManifest.xml